# Access ViewData Using  JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I am developing a mvc application.I  wrote a jquery for different operations and saved in to a js file named my.js. And i included that js file into my page.

```
 <script src="../../Scripts/my.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can i access ViewData from that js file. I tried many methods.But didnt worked yet.
The code i used to access ViewData from js file is shown below.

```
 var CalanderPreference = "<%= ViewData["CalanderPreference"] %>";
```

But it returning an error like  'Expected ; '

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewData is not accessible on client, because it exists only on view rendering.

You could serialize your view data to json on server side, write it to hidden field, and them parse it to javascript object on client side.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your javascript object on the view like in this example.

Put this into your view and not in a seperate file:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var saleYear = parseInt("<%=ViewData.Model.Sale24Hours.EndDate.Year %>");
                var saleMonth = parseInt("<%=ViewData.Model.Sale24Hours.EndDate.Month %>") - 1;
                var saleDay = parseInt("<%=ViewData.Model.Sale24Hours.EndDate.Day %>");
                var saleHour = parseInt("<%=ViewData.Model.Sale24Hours.EndDate.Hour %>");
                var saleMinute = parseInt("<%=ViewData.Model.Sale24Hours.EndDate.Minute %>");
                var saleSecond = parseInt("<%=ViewData.Model.Sale24Hours.EndDate.Second %>");
                var endSaleDate = new Date(saleYear, saleMonth, saleDay, saleHour, saleMinute, saleSecond);
                $("#countDownSale24").countdown({ until: endSaleDate, compact: true, format: "HMS" });
            });
        </script>
```